# Tokenize string with parameterised delimiter

Tags: sml

I need to tokenize string to list of words in Standard ML based on a delimeter which is to be passed as a function parameter. This is the code I have so far:

```
val splitter = String.token(fn (c:string,x:char) =>  c=x);
```

I tried this but i know its wrong .Please help me to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

the type of `c` is string while the type of `x` is char. They are not comparable. You can convert x to string with Char.toString.

```
splitter = String.token(fn (c:string,x:char) => c=Char.toString x);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard library function called `String.token`, but maybe you mean `String.tokens`:

```
- String.tokens;
> val it = fn : (char -> bool) -> string -> string list
```

You're not saying if your separator is a `string` or a `char`, but assuming it's a `char`,

```
fun splitter sep s = String.tokens (fn c => c = sep) s
```

You could also define it as such,

```
fun curry f a b = f (a, b)
val splitter = String.tokens o curry op=
```